# What's the point in the 'gas' parameter passed to function 'signTransaction'?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I am using web3.js v1 in order to sign and send transactions:

```
async function signAndSend(transaction) {
    let options = {
        to  : transaction._parent._address,
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas : SOME_GAS_AMOUNT
    };
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}
```

In order to compute how many gas units were used, I do:

```
let gasPrice = new BigNumber(await web3.eth.getGasPrice());
let bgnBalance = new BigNumber(await web3.eth.getBalance(PUBLIC_KEY));
await signAndSend(myTransaction);
let endBalance = new BigNumber(await web3.eth.getBalance(PRIVATE_KEY));
console.log(`Total cost: ${bgnBalance.minus(endBalance).div(gasPrice)} gas units`);
```

I observe the following:

- When `SOME_GAS_AMOUNT` is too low, I get `base fee exceeds gas limit`
- When `SOME_GAS_AMOUNT` is high enough, I always get the same total cost

My conclusion is, just use a large enough (hard-coded) value.

Am I right?

If yes, then what's the point in this parameter to begin with?

[The docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) for function `signTransaction` say:

> gas - String: The gas provided by the transaction.

What does "gas provided by the transaction" even mean? I thought that I was the one providing gas for the transaction to take place!

By the way, initially, I used to set the `gas` parameter as follows:

```
gas: await transaction.estimateGas({from: PUBLIC_KEY});
```

However, this occasionally gave me the `base fee exceeds gas limit` error.

So I figured I was kind of on the wrong track with that one.

In short, any clarifications on the `gas` parameter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for you help!

UPDATE:

I am not asking about the meaning of the term "gas".

Please refer to my observation (quoting from above):

I observe the following:

- When `SOME_GAS_AMOUNT` is too low, I get `base fee exceeds gas limit`
- When `SOME_GAS_AMOUNT` is high enough, I always get the same total cost

My conclusion is, just use a large enough (hard-coded) value.

Am I right?

If yes, then what's the point in this parameter to begin with?

If no, what exactly should I set this parameter to?

I initially used to set the `gas` parameter as follows:

```
gas: await transaction.estimateGas({from: PUBLIC_KEY});
```

However, this occasionally gave me the `base fee exceeds gas limit` error.

So I figured I was kind of on the wrong track with that one.

Comment: @smarx: Your proposed duplicate does not answer my inline questions. Moreover, it states something opposite to my observation: "**If you set a very high gas price, you will end up paying lots of ether for only a few operations**". Here, I explicitly stated that I see the same total cost no matter how high I set the `gas` parameter. I would be happy(ier) if you could refer to the specific doubts expressed in my question. I am not asking about the general meaning of the term "gas". Thank you.

Comment: When code `assert`s or executes some other invalid opcode, all remaining gas is consumed. So if you set the gas limit too high, you're losing more ether. Your call to `estimateGas` doesn't have the right transaction details. (E.g. it's missing the `to` and `data` fields.)

Comment: @smarx: So you reckon fixing my call to `estimateGas` will solve the `base fee exceeds gas limit` error???

Comment: You also have to have enough ether to cover `gasLimit * gasPrice`, even if you end up not needing to use all that gas. There's also a block gas limit, and miners may not attempt to run your transaction if it looks like it could exceed the limit for the block. So just using a really big number isn't a great strategy, though for  transactions you know will exceed, aiming just a little high is usually fine.

Comment: When you use multiple question marks like that, it looks (to me) like you're yelling. One question mark is sufficient to indicate a question. And yes, if you fix your `estimateGas` call, you should get the correct gas estimate, which will let you pass  the right `gasLimit`.

Comment: @smarx: Awesome, thanks, I will give it a try (was using the multiple question marks as an expression of surprise, not yelling).

Comment: @smarx: I'm looking at [the docs for function `estimateGas`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-estimategas), and I see no such parameters `to` and `data`. There are `from` (which I pass in my code), `gas` and `value`. Can you please explain your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't know what `transaction` is? Based on the documentation you pointed to, I assume you're using web3.js 1.0-beta, and `transaction` is the result of passing some arguments to a method on your contract (but before calling `send` on it). E.g. `contract.methods.foo(bar, baz).estimateGas({ from: ... })`? I was assuming you were just calling `eth_estimateGas`, which requires the full transaction details, but I think I was mistaken.

Comment: If my assumption above is correct, then your call to `estimateGas()` looks good to me. If that's returning an amount that's too low, you might consider that the gas cost of the transaction has changed between when you estimated the cost and when you sent the transaction, or perhaps it's dependent on the sender of the transaction and your `from` in the `estimateGas()` call doesn't match that. It's impossible to debug further without knowing the details of the transaction (and the contract source code if it's not on mainnet), the return value of `estimateGas()`, etc.

Comment: @smarx: No, `transaction` here (as shown in the code at the top of my question) is the "promise" returns from calling a contract method via web3 (referring to you previous comment).

Comment: @smarx: I don't see how the cost has changed, because I (used to) call `estimateGas` right before calling `signTransaction` and `sendSignedTransaction` (as shown at the top of my question). Will it help if I publish an MVP of the contract + web3 code in a separate question?

Comment: A `Promise` doesn't have a method called `estimateGas()`, so I don't think that's correct. It doesn't matter how quickly you call `sendSignedTransaction()` after `estimateGas()`. A transaction that is mined before yours (even earlier in the same block) can change the state of the contract.

Comment: Yes, sharing your code would help.

Comment: @smarx: Calling `myContract.methods.func()` returns a promise. I use this as the `transaction` in my code above. I will shortly post a `base fee exceeds gas limit` question. Thank you.

Comment: "`myContract.methods.func()` returns a promise." Citation needed. :-) (If you think it's a `Promise`, try calling `.then()` on it.)

Comment: @smarx: Posted the question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/56685/16043).

Comment: @smarx: And here is your citation in [the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=methods#methods-mymethod-call). Of course, I was slightly inaccurate (or wrong) calling it "a promise", as you get a promise only when you invoke `transaction.call` or `transaction.send`. But that's not my main issue here anyway, and I'd be happy if you could take a look at my other question. Thank you.

Comment: That's the documentation for  `myContract.methods.func().call()`, which _does_ return a `Promise`. **EDIT** Correct. (Just got your edit.)

Comment: @smarx: Yes, I just extended my previous comment to mention that.